# parallax scrolling - jumps when used mouse scroll wheel

Tags: jquery, parallax.js

I have come across a problem with parallax scrolling. When mouse scroll wheel used it starts jumping and it look where bad on chrome and very little jump in IE but fine in firefox.

here is the link for the [site](http://goguide.com.au/goguideresponsive/index_test.html).

The code i am using for parallax is

```
 <script>
var topDiv = document.getElementById("topDiv");
var speed = 1.5;

window.onscroll = function()
{
    var yOffset = window.pageYOffset;
    topDiv.style.backgroundPosition = "center "+ (yOffset / speed) + "px";
        scrolling = true;
}

</script>
```

If anyone can help me with it as i have looked for answers but not able to find.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue... check any parallax site on chrome with a mouse and it will jump.
There is a workaround that seems to work for me:
use NiceScroll Plugin so you don't actually use the default scroll...

I used it here:
http://www.xboxeventsus.com/

here is a link to nicescroll plugin:
http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/